# emacs stop scrolling after screen full of text using

Tags: emacs

I am a new emacs user and I feel very uncomfortable when I scroll a buffer using mouse in emacs. 
As I keep scrolling, emacs stops only when the last line of buffer hits the top visible row.
Though the minibuffer screams end of buffer, the scrolling keeps going on, which is very annoying.

How can I make emacs behave like any other editor/browser while scrolling using a mouse?

Comment: Are you still interested in this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .emacs ( ~/.emacs ). This works for me on OSX. More info [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmoothScrolling)

```
;; scroll one line at a time (less "jumpy" than defaults)

(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1))) ;; one line at a time

(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil) ;; don't accelerate scrolling

(setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't) ;; scroll window under mouse

(setq scroll-step 1) ;; keyboard scroll one line at a time
```